# Solve inequality $\lg ( x ^ { 3} - x - 1) ^ { 2} < 2\lg ( x ^ { 3} + x - 1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For $x$ real, solve $\lg ( x ^ { 3} - x - 1) ^ { 2} < 2\lg ( x ^ { 3} + x - 1)$

I've split this into two cases, first where the argument for the left lg is positive, and second for when it is negative. However, I do not know for what values $x ^ { 3} - x - 1$ is positive.

Comment: There's an ambiguity here: Is the left-hand side intended as $[\lg(x^3-x-1)]^{2}$ or as $\lg[(x^3-x-1)^2]$?

Comment: It must be the latter, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

we have to solve $$\lg(x^3-x-1)^2<2\lg(x^3+x-1)$$
it must be $$x^3-x-1\ne 0$$ and $$x^3+x-1>0$$ and we get
$$(x^3-x-1)^2<(x^3+x-1)^2$$
can you proceed?
and we can write
$$0<(x^3+x-1-x^3+x+1)(x^3+x-1+x^3-x-1)$$
Can you solve this?

Comment: Is the answer $(-inf, 0) U (1,inf)$?

Comment: i think this is not true.

Comment: I have one query . The moment you bring the two as square the second condition makes no sense

Comment: and from where do you get this?